# How to set a div (/its content) to rezise and center on any screen?

Tags: html, resize, size, screen, center

I need the banner on my website to center and resize according to the screen size the website is being viewed on (including mobile). I need it to center as in the actual center of the div is in the center of the screen, even if the div itself is wider than the screen it's being viewed on - so the left and right sides of it (/the image contained inside) are cropped/hidden off-screen.

Here's a page with the banner on as it is currently:
http://keshiheads.co.uk/test

Full size of banner image for reference: http://keshiheads.co.uk/Background.png

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=100%, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head> 

<body style="overflow-x:hidden;">

<div style="position:absolute;top:0;">

<div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;"><img src="Background.png" style="height:140px;"/></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use bootstrap, you can put the banner in a "container" class which will center your banner and then you can use css cut off points to make it responsive.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know of any (simple) guide of how yo do this? I am so lost with this type of coding. Apologies for being useless here!

Comment: You can just type "bootstrap responsive design" on youtube and choose any video. Dont worry about it everybody has to start somewhere.

Comment: Thanks again :) I shall check out some videos!